# How to calculate initial acceleration of a projectile motion?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, projectile

I have an object following a projectile motion, that hasn't got horizontal acceleration but only vertical *-g*.

What is the acceleration that I have to use in the second law of motion (*F = ma*) in order to calculate the force?

Comment: Hi Simone, you really need to show your own effort, and mark this as a homework question, otherwise it's a goner.  Have you read this site? http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/vectors/Lesson-2/Horizontally-Launched-Projectiles-Problem-Solving

Comment: Ok, I tried.....anyway, forget that part, did you read the link?

Comment: @Simone "homework question" is misleading since it might not actually be assigned to you as homework. The category it falls under is still considered a homework question on this site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not demonstrate prior effort.

Comment: try again, http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/vectors/Lesson-2/Non-Horizontally-Launched-Projectiles-Problem-Solv

Comment: @Simone you would need to know either its final velocity, or its displacement through some time interval with the time. Otherwise, initial velocity isn't enough by itself to determine a change in velocity aka acceleration.

Comment: In your post you say "Besides initial velocity, do I have to know other data?"  Now look at Obliv's comment.

Comment: @simone do you know the basic equations of motion? (called the kinematic equations) Take a look at those and try to find every equation that involves $a$ in it. Use those equations to solve for $a$ and look at the different types of information you need. Then solve for acceleration (if you can) and multiply it by the mass.

Comment: @simone be weary of the direction of displacement,velocity, acceleration as they are vectors.

Comment: @simone note that acceleration is defined as a change in velocity. By definition there is no horizontal acceleration in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a projectile problem, and assuming no air resistance or buoyancy, the only force is the weight mg acting constantly downwards, and the only acceleration is g. Neither of these is affected by initial velocity.

Answer (score 0):

Initial velocity has absolutely no effect on force. Any inertial frame must obey the same laws of physics as any other frame.

You asked what you need to know to calculate force and then said F=ma. I'm not entirely sure what you are getting at but you clearly need to know the mass and the acceleration. Now acceleration is the change in velocity over time (a=dv/dt) so if the particle CHANGES its velocity from it's initial velocity to another one all that matter is the change in v.